# Why does the child div's content break out of the parent div?

Tags: html, css

So I am making a web design: http://codepen.io/wostensen/pen/woxYgX

But I can't for the life of me understand why `.articles` won't stay in `.primary`. `overflow: hidden` does not give me a satisfactory result, as I want the user to be able to read all the blog posts. `display: block` does nothing at all to any parent element or even the element in question.

I can see that in Debug Mode + Developer Tools that `.articles` is flowing outside of `.primary` for no apparent reason. The footer is supposed to be the very end of the webpage, and the content is just flowing through it.

Are there anything I've simply missed?

Comment: Isn't this what you want (still needs some polishing)? https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/dOqzKb?editors=1100

Comment: Try removing `height:100%` from .primary OR as mentioned in above comment use overflow:auto if you want to fix the height and scrollbar on primary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class `.primary` do not give it a `height: 100%`. Change that to `auto`(or even remove it)

```
.primary {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  background: white;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

let the container decide what the height should be which will take into consideration its children as well

**Update:**

Noticed a container of the `.primary`(ie. `.content`) too has the `height: 100%`. Remove(or make it `auto`) from here as well.

Comment: Oh, cool. It worked!

But why doesn't the footer follow down the page as well? I have positioned it below the `content` div, so shouldn't it be pushed down?

Comment: Then I guess your `.content` too has the `height: 100%`. Let me check & update the answer.

Comment: I got it! That seems to have been the culprit. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Sure. Please accept so it can help others as well. Cheers